# In Customer Account Dashboard Page i have added link

Tags: magento2, customer-account, link

I have Created a link in account dashboard it is visible as shown in screen

shot below

[image]

when I click on the link it is showing just like these in the screenshot below

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2552811/5e81668539016e4f9622033455c999d0

But I need on clicking my custom link I need show the content as shown in the

screen shot below

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2552815/afa2f32d0f2be63d2596e75ae53626c1

**Layout Xml File**

> app/code/Custom/Customerdashboard/view/frontend/layout/customerdashboard_index_index.xml

code:

```
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Custom\Customerdashboard\Block\Index\Index" name="customerdashboard_index_index" template="customerdashboard_index_index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Please can Anyone help Me

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Share your demo page code in question.

Comment: Please check i Have updated the code in question @PrincePatel

Comment: Did you get my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Have to put these code in your Custom xml file

File Path:**app/code/Custom/Customerdashboard/view/frontend/layout/customerdashboard_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
        <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Custom\Customerdashboard\Block\Index\Index" name="customerdashboard_index_index" template="customerdashboard_index_index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>   
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">  
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customer_account_navigation_block" template="Magento_Theme::html/collapsible.phtml" before="-">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Account Dashboard</argument>
                        <argument name="block_css" xsi:type="string">block-collapsible-nav</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">nav items</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Dashboard</argument>
                                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Information</argument>
                                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/edit</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Address Book</argument>
                                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/address</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                </referenceContainer>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="content.top" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cat just add this to your layout file:

```
<update handle="customer_account"/>
```